# Error while posting data from one server to another server running on different ports

Tags: node.js, angularjs, http, nodemailer

> I am writing a program which will send a mail on clicking a button in html using nodemailer.
>       My Application server is running on 8383 port and the node server is running on 8080.
>       I am getting an error "POST `http://127.0.0.1:8080/Webcontent/api/mail` 404 (Not Found) `127.0.0.1:8080/Webcontent/api/mail`:1
>       Error: Cannot POST /Webcontent/api/mail"

```
Kindly look into the code and suggest a solution.


    server.js file


    var express  = require('express'),
    cors = require('cors');
    var app      = express();
    app.use(cors());    
    var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
    var database = require('./config/database');
    var morgan   = require('morgan');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var methodOverride = require('method-override');
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));         
    app.use(morgan()); 
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended':'true'})); 
    app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
    app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' })); 
    app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override')); 
    require('./app/routes.js')(app);
    app.listen(port);
    console.log("App listening on port " + port);

    routes.js file


    var User = require('./models/user');
    var Mail = require('./models/mail');
    module.exports = function(app) {
            app.post('http://127.0.0.1:8080/Webcontent/api/mail ', function(req, res) {
                console.log('inside post');
            Mail.fire(req.body.text1);
          console.log(req.body.text1);

        });


        app.get('*', function(req, res) {
                 console.log('fff');
            res.sendFile('index.html', { root: path.join(__dirname, './public') });

        });
    };

mail.js file

var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP",{
   service: "Gmail",  // sets automatically host, port and connection security settings
   auth: {
       user: "test@gmail.com",
       pass: "Test"
   }
});
exports.fire= function fire(username){
    smtpTransport.sendMail({  //email options
   from: "test@gmail.com", // sender address.  Must be the same as authenticated user if using GMail.
   to: "receive@yahoo.com", // receiver
   subject: "mail using nodemailer", // subject
   text: "mail body text" // body
}, function(error, response){  //callback
   if(error){
       console.log(error);
   }else{
       console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
   }

   smtpTransport.close(); // shut down the connection pool, no more messages.  Comment this line out to continue sending emails.
});
};


controller.js file// used to call the  function(sendmail) on button click 

$scope.sendMail = function() {
        //alert("inside createtodo");
        $http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8080/Webcontent/api/mail', $scope.formData).success(function(data) {
                //alert("inside success");
                $scope.formData = {};
                $scope.users = data;
                //console.log(data);
            })
            .error(function(data) {
                //alert("Bad Luck....");
                console.log('Error: ' + data);
            });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change in your route.js file:

```
app.post('/Webcontent/api/mail', function(req, res) {
    console.log('inside post');
    Mail.fire(req.body.text1);
    console.log(req.body.text1);
});
```